# How can a closing bracket be dealt with inside a regex match?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a set of text inside a bracketed item as a match group.

That text may or may not itself have a bracket in it.  To complicate matters, the text may or may not have quotes around it or exist at all, here are some examples of expected output:

```
[quote=John]abc[/quote] // John
[quote="John"]abc[/quote] // "John"
[quote='John']abc[/quote] // 'John'
[quote='Joh]n']abc[/quote] // 'Joh]n'
[quote='Joh[]n']abc[/quote] // 'Joh[]n'
[quote]abc[/quote] // match
```

The pattern I've come up with so far is `\[quote[=]?["]?([\s\S]*?)["]?\]|\[\/quote\]` but it is failing with the 4-5 examples above because it is seeing the first closing bracket

This would be used in `dart`

**EDIT**: The text in the middle `abc` should not be part of the match, meaning Match #1 should be `[quote...]` and match #2 should be `[/quote]`, as my current regex pattern does

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/7mYvmA/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewIt works in PHP but gives invalid group error in python or java

Comment: So, you understand that you need to provide the regex flavor. And the code you are using would also help to provide the solution you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It will be used in dart, but it seems like Python/Java variant seems to work well in dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
\[quote(?:=(.+?))?][^\]\[]*\[/quote]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0jRzhx/3)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `\[quote`: Match `[quote`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `=`: Match a `=`
  - `(.+?)`: Match 1+ of any character and capture in group #1
- `)?`: End non-capture group. `?` makes this optional match
- `]`: Match closing `]`
- `[^\]\[]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `[` and `]`
- `\[/quote]`: Match `[/quote]`

---

If you want to have 2 matches per line for opening and closing tags then you can use:

```bash
\[quote(?:=(.+?))?](?=[^\]\[]*\[)|\[/quote]
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/0jRzhx/3)

Comment: Can this be modified so it doesn't capture the text in between the [quote] and [/quote] as my original regex did?

Comment: It doesn't capture that text, it matches the text. Your original regex also matches a line with just `[/quote]`. Do you really want that behavior?

Comment: In regex my old one left the text in between unhighlighted, but yours highlights the entire line.  I think its because of the `|` I have in my original.  I tried adding the `OR` into yours but it breaks the first part of the match in capturing the extra `]`, but it does fix the issue of leaving the middle text alone.  It is breaking my implementation as its capturing too much text that I have to manipulate later

Comment: It would be better to use a lookahead like this: `\[quote(?:=(.+?))?](?=[^\]\[]*\[/quote])` if you want to match middle text

Comment: I would still need the trailing /quote to match, this is basically part of a larger recursive regex process, so it looks like the last one doesn't pick up the trailing [/quote]?

Comment: Recursive regex is not even supported in DART or Java. You are probably bit unclear on matching / capturing / lookahead. And you still didn't answer my question: are you fine with a regex that just matches a line with `[/quote]` ?

Comment: Yea its a homemade recursion, that does work If I can have a regex that matches the start and end tags but doesn't match the text in between the two tags.  Im not sure what you mean by a line with `[/quote]`, but in essence with my original pattern, match#1 is `[quote...]` and match#2 should be `[/quote]`.  Right now yours makes match #1 as `[quote...]text[/quote]`.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: See this demo with your original regex https://regex101.com/r/0jRzhx/2. It is matching a line that just has `[/quote]` with no opening tag. Is this fine with yiou?

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide another regex similar to what you had in question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. Seems like working:

```
\[quote(?:=|=\s*(['"]))?([^\]]*)\1?\]([^\[]*)\[\/quote\]
```

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=quote=)["'a-zA-Z\[\]]+(?=]abc)|(?<=quote])(?=abc)`

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TpKotk/1)

Where:

1. `(?<=quote=)` - everything that goes after `quote=`, **look-behind**
2. `(?=]abc)` - everything that goes before `]abc`, **look-ahead**
3. `["'a-zA-Z\[\]]+` - which symbols are allowed between parts 1 and 2.
4. `(?<=quote])` - everything that goes after `quote]`, **look-behind**
5. `(?=abc)` - everything that goes before `=abc`, **look-ahead**

Comment: I need the actual [quote=xxx] or [quote] to be a match as well, with the inner text as a match group

Comment: @Mark give me examples please. All the above strings are covered with the regex.